# How to raise verbosity of Installer.app?

Tags: terminal, macos, install

I'm having troubles with the system installer (`/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app`) where certain things are not installing and are not providing sufficient details in `/var/log/install.log`.

I get the dreaded "The installation failed" error:
[image: The installation failed]

Without sufficient details within the log as noted above.

Is there a way to raise verbosity so as to ascertain precisely where it may be failing within the install process?  I have been hoping that there is a flag that can be executed to increase this verbosity, but I've not found anything for

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer
```

as of yet when executing it from the shell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command line `installer` (in `/usr/sbin/installer`).

From the man page:

> The installer command is used to install Mac OS X installer packages to a specified domain or volume.

and use the `-verbose` or `-verboseR` options.

By example :

```
installer -verbose -pkg DeveloperTools.mpkg -target /
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's on macOS 10.12 you can use the new `log stream` command together with `--predicate` flag to narrow down the issues. Please note that log gives you a lot more output then syslog does/can.

`log stream --predicate examples:
    --predicate 'eventMessage contains "my message"'
    --predicate 'eventType == logEvent and messageType == info'
    --predicate 'processImagePath endswith "d"'
    --predicate 'not processImagePath contains[c] "some spammer"'
    --predicate 'processID < 100'
    --predicate 'senderImagePath beginswith "my sender"'
    --predicate 'eventType == logEvent and subsystem contains "com.example.my_subsystem"'`

You can also add `--level=debug` to get the maximum verbosity from log, and then narrow down the Installer.app issues with `--predicate`